# VS - switching between multiple sets of tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

On a larger Visual-Studio (2010) project, I find myself often working on different areas of an application, each requiring many files.

I end up with dozens of open documents

It would be great to instantly switch between sets of open files

I found Tabsstudio (tabsstudio.com) but this also decreases screen-space

What I would like is to switch similar to switching desktops (workspaces) in Linux.

(Hope this makes sense)

Is there any addin out there that can do this?

Comment: In VS2012 you have CTRL+Tab, which is like Alt+Tab on Windows. I'm not sure if this exists on VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

You can remember a group of files and then open them at once with the [Favorite Documents](http://vlasovstudio.com/favorite-documents/) extension.